# Unable to categorize 1 column on the basis of another in python

Tags: python, data-science

I have a Dataframe, In this data frame I have two Columns:
Complaint Type                  City
Noise - Street/Sidewalk         NEW YORK
Blocked Driveway                ASTORIA
Blocked Driveway                BRONX
Illegal Parking                 BRONX
Illegal Parking                 ELMHURST
Illegal Parking                 BROOKLYN
Illegal Parking                 NEW YORK
Blocked Driveway                BRONX
Illegal Parking                 KEW GARDENS

I want to find out how can I find the Complaint Types on the basis of City and the frequency of Complaint Type in a particular city using python?
The Data frame is NYC311 Service Request Data frame.

I want an output which describes:
City Newyork has 5 complaints and the frequency of each complaint is also being retuned.

:(

Found Unique cities as:

```
    unique_city =     nyc['City'].unique()
    unique_city[1]

    #Finding the City with the highest complaints according to complaint types
    nyc['City'].value_counts()
    nyc['Complaint Type'].value_counts()
    nyc[['Complaint Type','City']].head()
```

Unable to categorize further

Comment: `groupby('city').count()` ?

Comment: Hey Anderson, no, it will give u count of the city and not the count of each complaint types with respect to city

Comment: Perhaps `groupby(['city','complaint']).count()`? It's hard to help precisely, since there isn't apparent sample data in your question. If you could paste the result of `nyc.head()` that would help somewhat